# Compare Encrypted Bank Account Details without full Decryption

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, encryption-symmetric, sensitive-data

I am building a database that stores employee information, including bank account details. The bank account details are stored so that we can check for current or past staff using our company, which in our case might be a reason to be concerned about fraud. I have been reading up on SQL Server 2008 R2 Encrption and Decryption on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms179331(v=sql.105).aspx) and other places and have come up with the following sample script:

```
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM sys.symmetric_keys WHERE symmetric_key_id = 101)
    CREATE MASTER KEY ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'BankDetai!5'
GO

CREATE CERTIFICATE Employees_01 WITH SUBJECT = 'Employee Bank Account Details'
GO

CREATE SYMMETRIC KEY AccountNos_01
    WITH ALGORITHM = AES_256
    ENCRYPTION BY CERTIFICATE Employees_01
GO

CREATE TABLE #Bank_Accounts
( Id            INT IDENTITY(1,1)   NOT NULL    CONSTRAINT PK_BankAccount_Id PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (Id ASC)
 ,AccountNumber VARBINARY(128)      NOT NULL
 ,BankName      NVARCHAR(255)       NOT NULL
 ,CountryCode   VARCHAR(2)          NOT NULL
 ,CreateDate    DATETIME2(0)        NOT NULL
 ,EmployeeId    INT                 NOT NULL
 ,IsActive      BIT                 NOT NULL
 ,SortCode      VARBINARY(128)      NOT NULL
);

OPEN SYMMETRIC KEY AccountNos_01
    DECRYPTION BY CERTIFICATE Employees_01;

CREATE TABLE #SampleBankAccounts
( Id INT IDENTITY(1,1)
 ,AccountNumber VARCHAR(255)
 ,BankName      NVARCHAR(255)
 ,CountryCode   VARCHAR(2)
 ,EmployeeId    INT NOT NULL
 ,IsActive      BIT
 ,SortCode      VARCHAR(255))

INSERT #SampleBankAccounts
SELECT * FROM
(   SELECT
         '123456789'    AccountNo
        ,'Barclays'     BankName
        ,'US'           Country
        ,1              Employee
        ,1              IsActive
        ,'12-34-56'     SortCode
UNION
    SELECT
         '9876543210'
        ,'Barclays'
        ,'US'
        ,1
        ,0
        ,'12-34-56'
UNION
    SELECT
         '111111111111'
        ,'HSBC'
        ,'UK'
        ,2
        ,1
        ,'222222'
UNION
    SELECT
         'IBAN 123 456 9875 3215'
        ,'Nationwide'
        ,'ES'
        ,3
        ,1
        ,'00_gn321654'
)AS Samples
ORDER BY Employee

MERGE #Bank_Accounts        AS Target
USING #SampleBankAccounts   AS Source   ON Target.EmployeeId = Source.EmployeeId
                                            AND Source.AccountNumber = Target.AccountNumber
                                            AND Source.BankName = Target.BankName
                                            AND Source.CountryCode = Target.CountryCode
                                            AND Source.SortCode = Target.SortCode
WHEN NOT MATCHED
    THEN INSERT (AccountNumber, BankName,CountryCode,CreateDate,EmployeeId,IsActive,SortCode)
        VALUES (
             ENCRYPTBYKEY(KEY_GUID('AccountNos_01'),Source.AccountNumber)
            ,Source.BankName
            ,Source.CountryCode
            ,GETDATE()
            ,Source.EmployeeId
            ,Source.IsActive
            ,ENCRYPTBYKEY(KEY_GUID('AccountNos_01'),Source.SortCode));
GO


DROP TABLE #SampleBankAccounts
```

That seems to work fine, but now I need to take a variable e.g. `@AccountNo` and see if it matches any of the bank accounts we have stored (I'll use a stored procedure in all likelihood). I would much rather avoid decryption in any scripts if possible, so I wondered if it was possible to encrypt the `@AccountNo` variable and then compare it, so we might see a match:

```
DECLARE @MyTestBankAccount NVARCHAR(255) = '123456789'
DECLARE @MyEncryptedTestBankAccount VARBINARY(128)

OPEN SYMMETRIC KEY AccountNos_01
    DECRYPTION BY CERTIFICATE Employees_01;

SELECT @MyEncryptedTestBankAccount = ENCRYPTBYKEY(KEY_GUID('AccountNos_01'),@MyTestBankAccount)

SELECT
     AccountNumber
    ,EmployeeId
FROM Bank_Accounts
WHERE
    @MyEncryptedTestBankAccount = AccountNumber
```

This does not work; as you can see, I use an account number that should be present in the table, but no results are returned. I have tried to decrypt the account number column and compare it to the variable, but I get a load of Chinese characters coming out (much as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11338900/decryption-of-an-sql-encrypted-string)), and they do not match the characters created by encrypting and decrypting the variable, so that doesn't work for a match either...

So why does the following query (using data from above) not give me the encrypted and decrypted values for the account details? Can I use this method to search employee bank accounts against a given bank account?

```
OPEN SYMMETRIC KEY AccountNos_01
    DECRYPTION BY CERTIFICATE Employees_01;
SELECT
     AccountNumber                                  AS Encrypted_AccountNo
    ,EmployeeId                                     AS EmployeeId
    ,CONVERT(NVARCHAR,DECRYPTBYKEY(AccountNumber))  AS Decrypted_AccountNo
FROM Bank_Accounts
```

Comment: Is storing the account number in plain text a truly wrong thing? If I'm a client and I know my account number, I can probably guess another without too much difficulty, right? If keeping the account # encrypted is a must, then what about adding another column with the account # hashed, most of the time the hashed account # would be unique in the database, but you could run into a scenario where you would need to load matching hashes until you find the correct account.

Comment: I think this question belongs on the Information Security SE site because it's really dealing with best workable practice and not a code issue.

Comment: Encrypting the account numbers is a must unfortunately, which means that it is a code issue for me, as I have failed to retrieve the encrypted bank account information from the database for use, whether explicitly in plain text or in some encrypted form. From the MSDN article it looks as though it should happen, but my script fails.

Answer (score 0):

So I found the answer: exit SQL Server and re-enter.

Something must have had to be updated to work, because now everything is fine.

> ~gentle screaming~